# How to add the volume bar charts in python?

Tags: python, finance, candlestick-chart

Hello I do this code to see the Candlestick Chart on the crypto currencies on Bittrex, but I would like to add the volume. How can I do this ?

At the beginning of my code I get the data from a JSON URL, which allows me to have the candlestick chart and when I get the data, I save the volume in 
`float(data['result'][i]['V'])` but I don't know how to plot the volume ...

Here is my code :

```
import urllib2
import json
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ohlc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import datetime as datetime
import numpy as np

l = []
date = []
date_intermediaire = []

response = urllib2.urlopen('https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=BTC-ETH&tickInterval=thirtyMin&_=')
data = json.load(response)
print data


for i in range(len(data['result'])-95,len(data['result'])):
    append_me = float(data['result'][i]['O']), float(data['result'][i]['H']), float(data['result'][i]['L']), float(data['result'][i]['C']), float(data['result'][i]['V'])
    l.append((append_me))
    date.append(data['result'][i]['T'])

ohlc = np.array(l, dtype=[('open', '<f4'), ('high', '<f4'), ('low', '<f4'), ('close', '<f4'), ('volume', '<f4')])


for i in range(0,len(date)):
    date[i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(date[i], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    date_intermediaire.append((date[i]-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())




xdate = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i) for i in date_intermediaire]




fig, ax = plt.subplots()
candlestick2_ohlc(ax,ohlc['open'],ohlc['high'],ohlc['low'],ohlc['close'],width=0.6)



ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(6))


def mydate(x,pos):
    try:
        return xdate[int(x)]
    except IndexError:
        return ''


ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(mydate))

fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

This is the results of my code, so far:

[image: candlesticks]

Answer (score 1):

> *I would like to add the volume. How can I do this ?*

### Add a "secondary" Y-axis + plot the volume-s against it

This is a standard way how to securely set a superposition of two different graphs on the same layout.

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx() # this setting does the job
```

Check [details in **documentation** and examples](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html) on doing it this way.
[image]

---

### As commented below:

Either may "compose" gap-less layout of two sub-plots, or better set the mandatory scaling, so as to share the X-axis base.

[image]

( `pyplot` tooling permits doing this
like `ax2 = fig1.add_subplot( 111, sharex = ax1, frameon = False )`,
so pretty well doable in multiple manners, just keep walking to tweak settings and polish the `ax1` and `ax2` axis-ticks and labels to best meet your flavour )

Comment: Ok thank you may you have an easy example to do this kind of thing ? Because I never do this. Thank you very much !

Comment: I try to add this line but I does not work at all : `ax2 = fig.add_subplot( 111, sharex = ax, frameon = False )
ax2.hist(ohlc['volume'])`

Comment: Sorry I don't achieve to do this... I can't accept your answer because it does not help me :/

Answer (score 0):

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
```

Handy way to split the chart so you can put volume at the bottom and candles on the top